# What type of distribution is this when we know this mgf?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

What type of distribution does $X$ have when $$m_X(t)=\frac{\lambda^\alpha}{(\lambda-bt)^\alpha}$$ is our moment generating function of $X$?

Comment: @AnyAD I recognise it will be a gamma distribtion, but I am unsure of the parameters. Is it just gamma$(\alpha,\lambda)$?

Comment: The MGF of the Gamma distribution is $M(t)=(1-\frac{t}{\lambda})^{-\alpha}$, as you say. So we can divide through by $b$ and the parameters should be $(\alpha,\frac{\lambda}{b})$